# Use Rating Bar in Cardview

Tags: android, android-cardview, ratingbar

I have to visualize a set of cardview and each one must have a rating bar with five stars.
I used the code below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/card_title"
        android:text="@string/titolo"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/icons"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />



    <android.widget.RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

but I can't see the raing bar in my cardview. Where is the problem?
Please help me, thanks

Comment: Due to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in TextView. change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="titolo"
            android:textColor="#123456"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


        <android.widget.RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

It is because of the width `match_parent`, as you re giving orientation as `match_parent` it is taking whole screen width. Change it as above.

Answer (score 0):

Change `LinearLayout` orientation to verticle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your layout is that you have set the **LinearLayout** Orientation to horizontal. And your **TextView** is set to match_parent and after that you have added **RatingBar**. So it'll go outside screen.

Change your **orientation** to **vertical**  and try.